# How can I take a list of points that create a line and extend them into polygons inward of a certain length?

Tags: python, geometry, polygon

I have gps coordinates. They are just points that create an outline in a few different places, . I want to be able to have a script convert these points into polygons that extend X distance inwards, and also- a way for them to extend both inwards and outwards.

So if I had something like this:

(dots are points)

```
00000000000000000
00000000000000000
00............000
00.0000000000.000
00.0000000000.000
00.0000000000.000
00.0000000000.000
00.0000000000.000
00............000
00000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

I could run this program with a distance of 1 and "inwards", and I would end up with a polygon of # shape:

```
00000000000000000
00000000000000000
00&&&&&&&&&&&&000
00&&&&&&&&&&&&000
00&&00000000&&000
00&&00000000&&000
00&&00000000&&000
00&&&&&&&&&&&&000
00&&&&&&&&&&&&000
00000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

So far I have tried using circles and then reducing them but it seems wrong / not really feasible. This isn't being performed on a grid, actually it used floats for coordinates.

Any libraries that could do this as well are appreciated.

Comment: No, a list. Each of the closed shapes are in their own separate one also.

Comment: Sure, they all have hundreds of points. Not necessarily clockwise or counterclockwise, just from one point to the next style travel. 

 `-87.591604621628392,45.096611340705195,
 -87.58854379668621,45.090842359416861,
 -87.589388527669584,45.086618423968154,
 -87.592979043889585,45.085140007205247 ....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDAL/OGR is another option.  Ultimately what you want to do is a buffer.  To expand your polygons shape outward use a buffer with a positive buffer distance, inwards it would be negative buffer distance. The following is a simple example using a shapefile.  Not sure what format your data is in, but I would be surprised if GDAL/OGR can't read it.

```
import osgeo.ogr
# using ESRI Shape file in this example but there are a number
# of different files this lib supports: http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_formats.html
driver = osgeo.ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
osgeo.ogr.UseExceptions()

# Create a data source using the driver...
dataSource = driver.Open("/home/user1/data.shp")

# Get the layer
lyr = dataSource.GetLayer()

# Select the feature in this case using an attribute query
lyr.SetAttributeFilter("column = 'value'")

# verify that you have a feature selected
print 'features in layer:', lyr.GetFeatureCount()

# get the firest feature from the layer
feature = lyr.GetNextFeature()

# get the geometry from the feature
geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()

# perform a 100 unit buffer, not sure what units the coordinates of the 
# the data you have are in.
bufferGeom = geom.buffer(100)

# bufferGeom is a geometry object, which is described here:
# <http://cosmicproject.org/OGR/ogr_classes.html#Geometry>
```

The following is a fantastic resource for getting started with working with spatial data using GDAL/ORG: http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/

Api docs: http://cosmicproject.org/OGR/ogr_classes.html

finally here is the link to the GDAL/OGR page. http://www.gdal.org/

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely

Shapely is a very good 2d computational geometry library; the way I understand it, it reduces your problem to a single line of code.

Comment: Are you speaking of the erosion/dilation methods?

Comment: yeah; check out the examples. You get plenty of control about how to handle corners and so as well. Doing this stuff in a general and robust way from scratch without a library is very hard, and afaik shapely is the best library out there, so it pays to see if you can coax it into your specifics.